# Access the MDI toolbar menu with AutoHotKey ControlSend

Tags: autohotkey

[image]

Automating a process that is being run on a RDP session, I have to use ControlSend, and not Send command in AutoHotKey.

The WindowSpy doesn't find any control on the MDI toolbar, and there are no shortkey to the menu item I want to access (Filter..). How may I open the toolbar and select the item?

I've tried

ControlSend, ahk_parent, {alt}, ahk_class FNWND3170 ;Open project folder in treeview

But with no success.

I've considered using AutoIT, but I don't think that would help as the AutoIt spy doesn't pick up the control either.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but think of the RDP window (or even full screen) as an ever-evolving bitmap image.  Your PC and autohotkey have no idea what is behind the picture.  Can you run the ahk script in the remote pc itself?  Keep in mind, the RDP client handles your mouseclicks and keyboard (and even voice) entirely by re-directing inputs, etc.  So best bet is to do a mouse click in the appropriate spot by running a script from outside the window:

```
CoordMode, TargetType [, RelativeTo]
Click, 44, 55 ; Clicks the left mouse button once at coordinates 44, 55 (based on CoordMode).
```

Use the CoordMode "RelativeTo" flag to set to "Relative" so coordinates are relative to the active window.  You may have to click twice, once to activate the RDP window and then to click at the mouse position.

See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm and https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm for info.

Hth,

Comment: I am running the script on the RDT itself, and it works great as long as I use ControlSend commands and even though I am not connected to the RDP session. Ordinary Send commands and MouseClicks requires the RDP session to be active which is not what I need. Perhaps AutoHotKey is not my best option for automating a program process on the RDP? Got any tips on what might be?